# Creating metadata for binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary, metadata

I have a binary file I'm creating in C++, I'm tasked to create a metadata format to describe the data that it can be read in Java using the metadata.

One record in the data file has Time, then 64 bytes of data, then a CRC, then a new line delimiter.  How should the metadata look to describe what is in the 64 bytes?  I've never created a metadata file before.

Comment: I think that "schema" or "IDL" (Interface description language) would be better than "metadata" to describe what you want to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want to generate a file which describes *how many* entries there are in the data file, and maybe the time range. Depending on what kind of data you have, the metadata might contain either a per-record entry (RawData, ImageData, etc.) or one global entry (data stored as float.)

It totally depends on what the Java-code is supposed to do, and what use-cases you have. If you want to know whether to open the file at all depending on date, that should be part of the metadata, etc.

Comment: do you have an example or point me to a website of a good example for a metadata structure?

Comment: Take a look at Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata -- ID3 tags for MP3 or EXIF data for JPEG is a popular example. But whether your metadata is any good _totally_ depends on the use case. For instance, ID3 tags in MP3s won't help you if you're interested in the frequency distribution of a song. Defining metadata without use cases is worthless.

Comment: The use case is the Java app will take the binary file and metadata and create a csv file from it.

Comment: No. The use case can be: "The Java app wants to read the metadata and create a CSV with the time range." or something like that. Otherwise, create an empty metadata file, which will produce an empty CSV file and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you have the design backwards.

First, think about the end.

- What result do you want to see?  A Java program will create some kind of .csv file?
- What kind(s) of file(s)?
- What information will be needed to do this?

*Then* design the metadata to provide the information that is needed to perform the necessary tasks (and any extra tasks you anticipate).

Try to make the metadata *extensible* so that adding extra metadata in the future will not break the programs that you are writing now.  e.g. if the Java program finds metadata it doesn't understand, it just skips it.